# Weird underscore variable name created in the NodeJS shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I discovered the following behavior in the NodeJS shell:

```
$ node
> function foo () { _ }
undefined
> _
undefined
```

Why is the `_` variable defined? I expected to get `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`.

If I create an arrow function, the `_` will be the function reference:

```
$ node
> () => _
[Function]
> _
[Function]
> _.toString()
'() => _'
```

Why is this happening?

After calling `toString()` on the `_` variable, the `_` is converted into string:

```
> _
'() => _'
```

I tried to use `_ => ()` and we have the same issue:

```
$ node
> _ => {}
[Function]
> _
[Function]
> _.toString()
'_ => {}'
> _
'_ => {}'
```

I'm using `node v5.6.0`. This is not reproducible in a file but only in the NodeJS shell.

Comment: It's not an exact dupe but the answer is there. Basically, Node.js assigns the value of the last expression to `_`. [Official docs on the matter.](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features) Try typing in this: `1 <enter> _ <enter>`. The value of `_` will be `1`.

Comment: @MikeC Post it as an answer, not in the comments. Or flag as duplicate.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz I did flag it. Just threw in the comment for a brief explanation.

Comment: @MikeC Makes sense. Thanks! :-) So, it's a feature, not a bug. Learned something new.